# Add more properties to the currentUser() object

Tags: wakanda

Is it possible to add user specific properties (next to userName, fullName, ID) to the `directory.currentUser()` object?

**Result: directory.currentUser()**

```
{
    "result": {
        "userName": "jsmith", 
        "fullName": "John Smith", 
        "ID": "12F169764253481E89F0E4EA8C1D791A"
    }
}
```

http://livedoc.wakanda.org/HTTP-REST/Authenticating-Users/directorycurrentUser.303-815875.en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. However don't consider it as a drawback:

I suggest you to keep the `directory` as the authentication service of your application and store your user profile information on another entity (called `userProfile`, `userInfo`, `client`, ...).

This entity should be created just after the signup / first login of the user. It should have an attribute (for example `auth`) with the same value as the `ID` retrieved from the `directory.currentUser` function.

This way when the user makes a login, you fetch his profile searching the entity

```
where auth = ID
```

and consume / update his information there.

The solution is very effective if you want to keep separated your authentication system and your model. You will maintain the flexibility to rely on a different authentication system or make a dedicated micro-service later.